# How to retain my inputs using localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do is when i `typed` or `selected` on my inputs if i refreshed the page its still retain the values.

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/71/

script:

```
document.querySelector('#fname, #lname, #email, #reemail, #password, #gender, #bmonth, #bday, #byear').innerHTML = "";

var save = document.createElement('input,select');
document.querySelector('#fname, #lname, #email, #reemail, #password, #gender, #bmonth, #bday, #byear').appendChild(save);

if (!save.value) {
save.value = window.localStorage.getItem('value');
}

save.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
window.localStorage.setItem('value', save.value);
}, false);
```

Comment: You want to store them when user click `Create Account` button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following event handler on top of the `document.ready` that will call when any field value get change and store value in `localStorage`.

### [Complete Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/5kcsn/72/)

(Fill the data and click on run in the demo page will get reload but data will remain same)

```
$('#fname, #lname, #email, #reemail, #password, #gender, #bmonth, #bday, #byear').on("change", function () {
    localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val())
});
```

And following code will restore the value from `localStorage` on page load

```
$('#fname, #lname, #email, #reemail, #password, #gender, #bmonth, #bday, #byear').each(function (ind, val) {
    if ($(val).attr("id") != "gender") {
        $(val).val(localStorage.getItem($(val).attr("id")))
    }
    else {
        if (localStorage.getItem($(val).attr("id")) == "male")
            $("#gender[value=male]").prop("checked", true);
        else
            $("#gender[value=female]").prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice code, bookmarked! What do you use as `debugger;`?